# Simple HTML/CSS positioning issue

Tags: html, css

For some reason I think I'm forgetting something here. Below is my code:

```
<style type="text/css">
#content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="content">
<h1>what</h1>
foofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoofoo
</div>
```

When that loads, it shows this:

[image: grab]
http://grab.by/6Mhp

The text is not inside the box. Why...? And how to fix?

Comment: very interesting, can you try putting a wrapper <p> around the long string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the style

```
word-wrap:break-word;
```

on your `#content`

```
#content {
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    background: orange;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

Comment: Weird I have to write that now. I wrote a website last night that didn't have that style at all, and now I have to use it? It's so weird. :\

Comment: That because your text doesn't have spaces, causing the element to be long. So you have to force the `#content` to break these words. It's just like `notepad`, you can activate and deactivate `word-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think CSS will automatically break words into pieces to fit into the *div*.  You could use `overflow:hidden` to hide the overflow.  The example you already use should work fine if you have words that don't exceed the size of the div.

You can also use `word-wrap:break-word` but, IIRC, that requires either IE or CSS3 (though that probably represents a lot of browsers out there).